# How to get Teams Organization Hierarchical data in C# using Graph API

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

In microsoft teams, there is a tab titled "Organization", which shows something like this:
[image]

Is there any way I can get this data in C# by using Graph API?

Right now I have

```
var users = await graphClient.Users.Request().GetAsync();
```

which returns an array of all users, and each user has their name and job title. This is not enough to make the org chart, because it does not tell how different users relate. What Graph API call do I need to make in order to get the data to make the org chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Microsoft Graph SDK for C#, you can use the code below to get users with the manager:

```
var usersWithMgr = await graphServiceClient.Users.Request().Expand("manager").GetAsync();
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you, my final api call looks like             var users = await graphClient.Users.Request().Expand("manager")
            .Select(u => new { u.DisplayName, u.JobTitle, u.AccountEnabled}).GetAsync(); , u.AccountEnabled is important!

Comment: Is there a way to use `GraphServiceClient` with the user domain or a way to get clientID and connection details? Or those can only be provided by the administrator?

Answer (score 0):

I found out you can make a graph call to users to get all users in a domain, then foreach user, make a call as listed here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-manager?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp

This will get the manager, which can be manipulated into a hierarchical view.

UPDATE:

```
            var users = await graphClient.Users.Request().Expand("manager")
            .Select(u => new { u.DisplayName, u.JobTitle, u.AccountEnabled}).GetAsync();
```